# Sorting array of object inside reduce in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, reduce

I am trying to do sort inside the `reduce` and I thought I have everything correct but still my result is not sorted as desired.

Here is the code snippet I have:

```
var studentInfo = [
{
    studentId: 1,
    addresses: [
        {street: '123 Main St'},
    ]
},
{
    studentId: 2,
    addresses: [
        {street: '456 Front St'}
    ]
},
{
    studentId: 3,
    addresses: [
        {street: '100 MLK St'}
    ]
}
];

function appendAddress(studentId, newAddress) {
  return studentInfo.reduce(function (info, student) {
    if (student.studentId === studentId) {
        student = {
            studentId: student.studentId,
            addresses: student.addresses.concat(newAddress).sort(function (address1, address2) {
                return address2.street - address1.stree;
            })
        };
    }
    info.push(student);

    return info;
}, []);
}

var newAddress = {
street: '166 Devil St'
}

console.log('Result: ' + JSON.stringify(appendAddress(2, newAddress)));
```

I am getting result as

```
Result: [{"studentId":1,"addresses":[{"street":"123 Main St"}]},{"studentId":2,"addresses":[{"street":"456 Front St"},{"street":"166 Devil St"}]},{"studentId":3,"addresses":[{"street":"100 MLK St"}]}]
```

instead of

```
Result: [{"studentId":1,"addresses":[{"street":"123 Main St"}]},{"studentId":2,"addresses":[{"street":"166 Devil St"},{"street":"456 Front St"}]},{"studentId":3,"addresses":[{"street":"100 MLK St"}]}]
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: There's a typo in your sort: `stree` instead of `street`. You're also substracting two strings which will result in NaN

Comment: It seems like you're just trying to add a new address to an existing student, and add the student if it's not yet there. Is that right? If so, why use `.reduce()` and `.sort()`? Maybe you could explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

As to the sorting issue, if that was the main thing you were wondering about, you do indeed have a typo as the comment above noted, and also, performing subtraction on non-numeric strings won't get you very far. I used `.localeCompare` in the solution above.

If you wanted to copy the objects as you were appending, that can still be done more simply, but I don't know if that's what you actually want.

```js
var studentInfo = [
  {studentId: 1,addresses: [{street: '123 Main St'}]},
  {studentId: 2,addresses: [{street: '456 Front St'}]},
  {studentId: 3,addresses: [{street: '100 MLK St'}]}
];

console.log(addAddress(2, {street: "1234 56th Ave"}));

function addAddress(studentId, address) {
  const idx = studentInfo.findIndex(o => o.studentId === studentId);
  if (idx !== -1) {
    return [...studentInfo.slice(0, idx), {
      studentId,
      addresses: [...studentInfo[idx].addresses, address].sort((a,b) => a.street.localeCompare(b.street))
    }, ...studentInfo.slice(idx+1)];
  } else {
    return [...studentInfo, {studentId, addresses:[address]}];
  }
}
```

But now you're having two different copies of the data with some shared objects.

Comment: i was looking to append if student already exist otherwise create new one.

Comment: @αƞjiβ: Yes, I know. That's what I wrote. I added another solution to more closely resemble your original result where objects that were mutated are now copied instead. Are you taking an immutable approach to your code?

Comment: I see. Then the second solution prevents mutation.

Comment: I removed the first solution, and tweaked the no-mutation version.